# Use WebService Assembly like "sample" assembly

Tags: web-services

I have a small question:
Can we use a compiled web service reference assembly like we use "sample" assembly?
I mean something like following:
1. Add reference to assembly in the references 
2. add namespace to using (using mywebservice)
3. use it in code like:

```
`var result = mywebservice.Service1.GetSomething()?`
```

Why I'm asking?
It's because of I tried but I get a "strange" error: Cannot load assembly ""MyService.dll version, and so on.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: would be useful to actually give the full error message in detail. it seems that you may not be adding the reference to the web service or DLL in question. you need to create the Service1 instance in your case before you can access "GetSomething" method.

Comment: where? :) the comment is empty with no code but only "this is the code"

Comment: This is the code 'var service = new TheWebService.Service1();
   service.ConcatStrings("A","B");' and this is the error: Could not load file or assembly 'Service1.dll, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: did you add the service1.dll to the project references? Where did you obtain the DLL from? how was it built?

Comment: yes. I Added the service1.dll to the project references. I obtained it using the ServiceDescriptionImporter and then I compiled the CodeCompileUnit. The idea is that if I load it using: Assembly.LoadFrom -> then CreateInstance -> then invoke it works. The question is why it can't be loaded "by default"?

Comment: it should be. if you right click and add service reference and follow through that wizard, it will all be added and should just work. Not sure why you are using the CodecompileUnit?